# Better way to debug unwanted SQL query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I am logging hibernate SQL queries with application.properties values:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

I can see that each REST request(even the ones, without any body and any pre/post authorization) sends 3 SQL SELECT queries. I want to debug which classes do these unwanted queries, but I can not find them.

I search for bad behaving class in IntelliJ with debug mode inside of Debugger class execution list. I am jumping into each class and trying to find something. ***Is there any better way to debug problem like this ?***

All I know, is that:

1. I do not have any custom filter, that intercepts request AND sends query to DB.
2. My CORSFilter implementing Filter with @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) is before unwanted SQL queries.
3. My OtherFilter extending OncePerRequestFilter runs after unwanted SQL queries.

Comment: You could put a breakpoint in a JDBC method.

Comment: But I do not have any repository/database call, that I know of.

Comment: I thought that you could see from your logs that DB calls were being made?

Comment: I can see it in logs, but I do not know which class runs this SQL statement.

Comment: Try setting a method breakpoint on `ResultSet.next()` -- that's likely to be used.